# Qt invoke method with QVariant

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following function :

```
class TestClass: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:      
  Q_INVOKABLE QString test() { return QString("test"); }
};
```

And I want to invoke the test method, but get the return type as QVariant, not as QString. So I tried this :

```
 TestClass obj;
 QVariant returnedValue;
 bool rslt=  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&obj, "test", Qt::DirectConnection,
     Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue)
     );
 QString strVar = returnedValue.toString();
```

but it doesnot work, invoke returns false;

If get the return type as QString it works, but unfortunately this will not be usable for me, cause I need to know the return type before calling the function.

```
 QString r;
 bool rslt=  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&obj, "test", Qt::DirectConnection,
     Q_RETURN_ARG(QString, r)
     );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect method return type via [`QMetaMethod::returnType()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#returnType), and then construct the return value receptor using [`QGenericReturnArgument`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericreturnargument.html).

[Here is some code for inspiration](https://gist.github.com/andref/2838534)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I did small code example that it works I will post it as answer. But still I am not clear why it works , if you maybe can explain

Answer (score 0):

this is my working example

```
class TestClass: public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:      
  Q_INVOKABLE MyStruct test() { return MyStruct(5); }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)
int ttr=qRegisterMetaType<MyStruct> ();

TestClass obj;    

int thetype = QMetaType::type("MyStruct");
void *v = NULL;
QVariant returnedValue (thetype,v);
void* data = returnedValue.data();

bool rslt=  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&obj, "test", Qt::DirectConnection,
     QGenericReturnArgument("MyStruct", data )
     );

bool can = returnedValue.canConvert<MyStruct> ();
MyStruct structm = returnedValue.value<MyStruct>();
```

Comment: You can make this example even more universal by fetching the return type name from QMetaMethod instead of providing it explicitly  (so you have to first find the metamethod of your QObject and then get the type via QMetheMethod::typeName()).